# How to read a csv file and create a .yml file dynamically for each entry in csv file

Tags: python, csv, yaml

I have written this code to create a yml file with UUID as it's name. I need to read csv file and dynamically create a .yml file for each entry in the .csv

```
import uuid
import yaml

with open('sample.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    d = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
d['id'] = 'id'
print(d)

d['id']=id
f = open('Test.yaml','w+')
print(d)
yaml.dump(d, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `d['id'] = 'id'; print(d); d['id']=id` lines?

Comment: I tried that for having my yml file to be with UUID everytime it generated a new yml file. Or I can remove d['id'] = 'id'; print(d); this part and just use the other part to name the  yml file with the UUID.

Comment: The [built-in `id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) doesn't produce a UUID, and the way you're using it, you're assigning the `id` function *itself* to `d["id"]` - also not a UUID. You need to call one of the `uuid[1|3|4|5]()` functions in the [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module - I'd use [`uuid.uuid4()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4).

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format. What you get, because you use the outdated PyYAML package, is a YAML file according to the 10+ year old YAML1.1 specs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a file for each row in the csv, all you need to do is read in the csv file and move through the lines one by one. One way to do that:

```
import csv
with open("file_name.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # open new yaml file
        # write row to file
        # close the file
```

Is this what you had in mind?

You will want to create unique file names (otherwise you'll keep writing over the same file with every new row). You can also do more complex writing to the file if you use `str.split(',')` on each `row` in order to format the yml files.

Comment: I wanted it to to be reading the csv file which has unique rows (Like Tactic number which would be different for each row. so based on that it creates a unique yml file with UUID)

Comment: So each column is a unique element, and each row is a new entry, with an item in each column/element? Since the columns of each row will have the same labels, I think you could just do row.split(',') to get a list of the items in that row. Then it's just a matter of indexing that list as you want to put things where you want them in the yml file